# append's return value in Go

Tags: go, slice

After reading [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices) article, I have some question in mind.

Basically, why we need to store the return value of `append()` in Go? How is the function actually implemented?

I have tried to replicate (sort of) the mechanism of append in C (which is the first language used to implements the Go language, if I'm not mistaken). I used `malloc()`, instead of an array as it will not deallocate the slice after the function returns.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct SliceHeader {
    int length;
    int capacity;
    int *zerothElement;
} SliceHeader;

void append(SliceHeader *sh, int element)
{
    if (sh->length == sh->capacity) {
        // grow capacity size
        sh->capacity += 10;
        realloc(sh->zerothElement, sh->capacity);
    }
    sh->zerothElement[sh->length] = element;
    sh->length++;
}

SliceHeader * make(int capacity)
{
    SliceHeader *sh = (SliceHeader *) malloc(sizeof(sh));

    sh->length = 0;
    sh->capacity = capacity;
    sh->zerothElement = (int *) malloc(capacity * sizeof(int));

    return sh;
}

int main()
{
    SliceHeader *sh = make(3);

    append(sh, 5);
    append(sh, 10);
    append(sh, 15);

    append(sh, 20); // exceed the original capacity, should reallocate

    for (int i = 0; i < sh->length; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *((sh->zerothElement)+i) );
    }

    free(sh->zerothElement);
    free(sh);

    return 0;
}
```

(I omit NULLs checking to show only the relevant part to the main question).

If I'm using this code, I can use `append()` without the need to store its return value and no needs to create a new slice header.

So how is the implementation of `append()` function in Golang that makes it needs to store a new slice header? Even if the `zerothElement` uses an array, doesn't it means that it will need to change the array only instead of the whole slice header?

What am I missing here?

Thanks :)

Comment: The first argument to `append` is a slice header, not a pointer to a slice header.

Comment: @Muffin Top Ah, sure I’ve missed that. Thanks, mate

Answer (score -1):

> Basically, why we need to store the return value of append() in Go?

You only need to store this value if you intend to use the slice with the appended value.

> How is the function actually implemented?

Go is open source, just consult the source code. (Btw: This is uninteresting.)